# Making new txt file with size info

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create new csv or txt file with information of input and output file size(for all file in files) for example: SIZE OF INPUT FILE IS 42, SIZE OF OUTPUT FILE IS 320, all this according previous part of my code. Thank you :D

```
files = glob.glob('*.csv')

for file in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(file, header= None)

    df1 = df.iloc[:, :4].agg(['sum','max','std'])

    df1.columns = range(1, len(df1.columns) + 1)

    s = df1.stack()

    L = ['{} of the {}. column is {}'.format(a, b, c) for (a, b), c in s.items()]

    output_file_name = "output_" + file

    pd.Series(L).to_csv(output_file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Do you want the file size in bytes ? Maybe check the import os module there are a couple functions in there that might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, for getting file size , you can use the `os` module:

```
Using os.path.getsize:

>>> import os
>>> s = os.path.getsize(r'C:\path\test.txt')
>>> s
6551
```

or :

```
os.stat(r'C:\path\test.txt').st_size
6551
```

The result returned is in bytes.